# IBM Rhapsody RulesComposer documentation?

Tags: customization, code-generation, rhapsody

The ADA rules for the Code Generation of Rhapsody by default, as far as I'm understanding it, relies on this java proyect <Rhapsody Instalation path\Sodius\RiA_CG\compiled_rules\RiA_CG.jar>

I have a big problem as I need to model an statechart and the generated code contains some bindings to OXF framework. I don't want to depend on a library that I don't know, I don't know how it behaves and I don't know its maintenance.

I have been spending weeks reading about customizing code generation in Rhapsody using RulesComposer, but the official documentation is like a recipe, you follow tones of steps but what you are doing is not really explained.

If someone can share me a video or a a link to a good explanation about it, even if it is not for the ADA language, I would be very grateful.